# Error: Chat.find(...).populate(...).populate(...).strictPopulate is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongoose

I am trying to populate group chat in mongoose and node and I receive the error that populate is not a function.

I use mongoose 5.12.9

Here the chatModel:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const chatModel = mongoose.Schema(
    {
        chatName: { type: String, trim: true },
        isGroupChat: { type: Boolean, default: false },
        users: [
            {
                type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: "User",
            },
        ],
        latestMassage: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            // required: false,
            ref: "Message",
        },
        groupAdmin: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "User",
        },
    },
    {
        timestamps: true,
    }
);


const Chat = mongoose.model("Chat", chatModel);

module.exports = Chat;
```

And then the find that I use:

```
const asyncHandler = require("express-async-handler");
const Chat = require("../models/chatModel");
// const chatModel = require('../models/chatModel');
const User = require("../models/userModel");

const accessChat = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const { userId } = req.body;

    if (!userId) {
        console.log("UserId param not sent with request");
        return res.sendStatus(400);
    }

    var isChat = await Chat.find({
        isGroupChat: false,
        $and: [
            { users: { $elemMatch: { $eq: req.user._id } } },
            { users: { $elemMatch: { $eq: userId } } },
        ],
    })
        .populate("users", "-password")
        .strictPopulate("latestMessage");

    isChat = await User.populate(isChat, {
        path: "'latestMessage.sender'",
        select: "name pic email",
    });

    if (isChat.length > 0) {
        res.send(isChat[0]);
    }
    else {
        var chatData = {
            chatName: "sender",
            isGroupChat: false,
            users: [req.user._id, userId],
        };

        try {
            const createdChat = await Chat.create(chatData);

            const FullChat = await Chat.findOne({ _id: createdChat._id }).populate("users", "-password");

            res.status(200).send(FullChat);
        } catch (error) {
            res.status(400);
            throw new Error(error.message);
        }
    }
});

module.exports = { accessChat, fetchChats, createGroupChat };
```

It show the chat in postman with post request using token

............................................................

and it show the Error---

"message": "Chat.find(...).populate(...).strictPopulate is not a function",
"stack": "TypeError: Chat.find(...).populate(...).strictPopulate is not a function\n    at D:\Project\ChatNET\backend\controllers\chatControllers.js:22:10\n    at asyncUtilWrap (D:\Project\ChatNET\node_modules\express-async-handler\index.js:3:20)\n    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\Project\ChatNET\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)\n    at next (D:\Project\ChatNET\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:144:13)\n    at D:\Project\ChatNET\backend\middleware\authMiddleware.js:18:13\n    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)"